# Facebook PHP sdk 500 Internal Server Error on windows server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii

I am trying to integrate Facebook php sdk with my application (build on YII framework) using yii-facebook-opengraph extension.

The problem arises once i am trying to authenticate to facebook. after authentication and redirects to the domain its throwing 500 internal server error.

Application hosted on windows server, PHP (5.2.17), Yii(1.1.14),parallel plesk(9.5).

The cause for 500 internal server is unknown. also checked the log but its of no help to trace the error.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: What I normally do when I get internal server errors is the following;
- Starting at the top, I echo a text (say: 'Hello World') with an exit(); command right after it and run the script. If this works, I move the echo and exit down the script and run it again. I keep repeating this untill I find the line of code which causes the 500 Internal Server Error. Try this; find the line of code, and post it here with about 10 lines of code around it. Then I will be able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Facebook's PHP SDK, version 4, requires PHP 5.4. Your question indicates that you're using an earlier version of PHP.